# Does Pandas Limit Importing Rows From Excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large excel workbook with many sheets inside of it.   I want to condense them into a single csv file, and I've been using this method.

Recently, it seems to stop importing after an unknown number of rows on the sheets with rows.

Is there a limit on `.to_csv` or `.read_excel` ?

The rows are in the ExcelSheets.xlsx, but missing in the TestReport.csv.

```
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel("""C:/ExcelSheets.xlsx""", sheet_name=None)

full_table = pd.DataFrame()

for name, sheet in sheets_dict.items():    
    sheet['sheet'] = name
    sheet = sheet.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('\n')[-1])
    full_table = full_table.append(sheet)

full_table.to_csv('TestReport.csv')
```

Comment: No, there's no limit other than your memory. And if you hit that limit you'll get an error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you have any suggestions about what would be causing the behavior of missing rows?

Comment: If you look at the data with excel, do you see anything in particular in the offending row?

Comment: Are you sure it's doesn't complete? Is it possible you're stopping the program before it finishes? Keep in mind looping with pandas is a very slow process